# Using a function or a type method?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a `Helper.swift` file to add some functions/methods that are useful in different parts of my app.

I was wondering what is the best practice (if there is one): create a class and only create type methods or just create functions?

Comment: I think you should use as class function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would generally lean towards using a type methods on an appropriately named type, in order to give your helper methods context and avoid polluting the global namespace.

In Swift, structs are an ideal candidate for this sort of construct:

```
struct Helper {
    static func helpfulMethod() { ... }
}
```

I also use embedded structs with static constants quite liberally in my top level types in order to group related constants within my code.

In writing custom Swift types, you should generally consider using structs first, and only resort to classes when inheritance, reference semantics (as opposed to the implicit copying with value semantics) or ownership semantics (`unowned`/`weak`) are required. In this case, your utility functions will be stateless, and there is no inheritance to speak of, so a struct should really be preferred over a class.

I would argue that in general, the Swift language is moving away from global functions in favour of the implicit namespacing provided by types (and protocols/generics). But it's still largely a matter of style/personal preference, and for something as simple as a utility function it's of little consequence.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to create a class or a struct. You can simply put the functions directly in Helper.swift file. And you dont even need to import this file by writing import statements.

To test it out create a file called helper.swift and just add the following lines of code to the file. **No class or struct is required.**

```
import Foundation

func addTwo(x: Int) {
    return x+2
}
```

To use this function in any other file just call the function with the required arguments.

```
let a = addTwo(9)
```

I prefer this method because when you call the function then you dont have to call it on an instance of a class/struct. Secondly, it leads to cleaner code as you don't have to make each function a class function or a static function.

Comment: I think @Nico realised this was an option, but was looking for a discussion of the merits of each approach (global function vs. type method). That's not to take away from your last paragraph, however, where you do discuss the benefits of this approach :).

Comment: @Stuart I just added this answer to point out that this is also a possibility. And the benefit of this approach is less code.

Comment: Yes indeed that's what I have done with some constant. It's faster indeed to write and maybe clearer in the file where you create them but I agree with @Stuart 's answer in the way that it gives a context. And I actually realize that it might help me when I don't remember the name of the method/constant but I do not the context (or the class in this case)

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer type method because by this way you can easily differentiate your methods.

Suppose you have 50 to 60 methods in which some methods are for designing purpose, some methods are for calculation purpose and some methods are for getting and posting data on server.

Now in this scenario, if you create all these methods as globally it will become hard to recognise and remember.

Now if you differentiate this methods in some class/struct like below:

- Methods which are use for Designing purpose make a `DesignHelper` class/struct and put all these methods into it as `class/static method`
- Methods which are use for calculation purpose make a `MathHelper` class/struct and put all these method into it as `class/static method`
- Methods which are use for process data with server make a `ConnectionHelper` class/struct and put all these method into it as `class/static method`

By using this way you can easily find out any of the method and it will also help in `auto completion`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Class functions through a single class work but generally those functions that are being used throughout your app will reuccur on the same objects. A cleaner way is to define your functions in extensions of the object that will use the function. You could put all your extensions in Helper.swift

e.g.

```
extension UIColor
{
    class func randomColor() -> UIColor
    {
        var randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        var randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        var randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

with usage like this `page.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()`

So you can still define your functions as class functions or object functions depending on the usage, but within the extension of the object.

This keeps your code clear so you dont route your calls through the helper throughout your code base. Its clearly defined for the object that will be needing the function. If you find code that does not make sense in an extended function then the function probably needs refactoring into more focused functionaly.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1:**

```
class Helper {
    class func classMethod() {
        // TODO: play something
    } 
}
```

And call it:

```
Helper.classMethod()
```

In Apple doc:

> Structures are always copied when they are passed around in your code, and do not use reference counting.

**Solution #2:**

```
struct Helper {
    static func classMethod() {
        // TODO: do something
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
Helper.classMethod()
```

I think *solution#2* better than *solution#1* because it's not increase reference counting.

UPDATED: I tested with `playground`. See the result below:

[image]
Hope this helps!

Comment: ok but in what is it better than just `func classMethod() {
        // TODO: play something
    } `?

Comment: With helper method you create an `instance method` is really not neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best practice but here is how I do it.

First I declare a protocol:

```
protocol UtilityType { }
```

Then I extend it (For example a utility function for UIViewController)

```
extension UtilityType where Self: UIViewController {
    func setDefaultTitleAttributes() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    }
}
```

And I use it like this

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setDefaultTitleAttributes()
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UtilityType {}
```

Comment: Extensions of protocols work only on Swift 2 if I'm not wrong.